# How do I get total addition of three group?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider, range

Here I three groups with range slider and input. I want to apply two things.

1. Multiplication of range slider and the input.
2. And at the end Addition of all multiplication.
   I have a different ID for all input types.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var t_sum=0;
  var rs=document.getElementById("range").value;
  var am=document.getElementById("amount").value;

  var k=0;
  $('.mul').each(function(){
        i++;
        var newID='multiplication-'+k;
        $(this).attr('id',newID);
        document.getElementById("multiplication").innerHTML = rs * am;
  })
  document.getElementById("addition").innerHTML= multiplication+k;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" class="range" id="range1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1">
<input type="text" id="amount1" value="10" disabled ><br>
<input type="range" class="range" id="range2" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1">
<input type="text" id="amount2" value="20" disabled ><br>
<input type="range" class="range" id="range3" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1">
<input type="text" id="amount3" value="30" disabled ><br>

<input type="hidden" id="multiplication" class="mul">
Addition of all multiplication <input type="text" id="addition" value="" disabled >
```

I know the code is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give common class to your `amt` input as well then use `index` value of each loop to get value of `amt` inputs and add total to your addition input.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".range").on("change", function() {
    var mult = 0;
    $('.range').each(function(i) {
      var selector_next = parseInt($(".amt:eq(" + i + ")").val()) //get input value
      mult += parseInt($(this).val()) * selector_next //multply..
      console.log($(".amt:eq(" + i + ")").val(), $(this).val())
    })
    $("#multiplication").val(mult)
    $("#addition").val(mult)
  })
  $(".range:first").trigger("change")

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="range" class="range" id="range1" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1">
<!--added class-->
<input type="text" class="amt" id="amount1" value="10" disabled><br>
<input type="range" class="range" id="range2" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1">
<input type="text" class="amt" id="amount2" value="20" disabled><br>
<input type="range" class="range" id="range3" min="0" max="12" value="0" step="1">
<input type="text" class="amt" id="amount3" value="30" disabled><br>

<input type="hidden" id="multiplication" class="mul"> Addition of all multiplication <input type="text" id="addition" value="addition" disabled>
```

Comment: I am not sure what is `multiplication` input use for :) .

Comment: For storing the data of inputs, and also getting the addition of all input's multiplication.

Comment: this answer your question or am i missing something here ?

Comment: Yes the answer is correct but why use ` $(".range:first").trigger("change") `

Comment: To trigger change event on page load you can remove that if you don't want to do calculation on page load.

Comment: What should I use instead of $("#addition").val(mult). Because in my code range slider data update in the console but those additions are not updated in the #addition input field.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233599/discussion-between-swati-and-anupam-mistry).